# Making sense of New Relic reporting

Tags: performance, ce-cache, caching, newrelic

Recently the site we've been working on has been attracting a lot more traffic.

We've been seeing high CPU spikes and recently installed New Relic.

Already we've been able to pinpoint a bottle neck but I'm seeing something in the reporting that I can't make sense of.

We're seeing a high transaction time on /article/undefined

My initial thought was that perhaps the second segment was wrong (typo, non-existent) etc but our article template has `require_entry="yes"` and in the `if no_results` will redirect to our 404.

I wonder if it's worthwhile moving our 404 outside of EE entirely if we're getting that much throughput on it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be a problem with a third-party add-on (extension most likely)?  Does the debug template output indicate where the delay is for that URL?

Comment: I had a problem like this once. There was a redirect to 404 in the 404 template.